# Notepad ++ Insert at the beginning of nth line that contains a string

Tags: notepad++, regex, find, find-and-replace

I am doing some Gcode machine instruction and I need to add an instruction in the beginning of the line where every 1st instance of `F 180.0` but skip the second

**eg**

```
G00 X 0.0000 Y 0.0000 Z 10.0000
G00 X 24.5230 Y 44.6619 Z 5.0000
G01 X 24.5230 Y 44.6619 Z 0.0000 F 180.0
G01 X 24.5585 Y 45.2432 Z 0.0000 F 180.0
G01 X 24.6723 Y 45.8451 Z 0.0000
```

**Would become**

```
G00 X 0.0000 Y 0.0000 Z 10.0000
G00 X 24.5230 Y 44.6619 Z 5.0000
M03 G01 X 24.5230 Y 44.6619 Z 0.0000 F 180.0
G01 X 24.5585 Y 45.2432 Z 0.0000 F 180.0
G01 X 24.6723 Y 45.8451 Z 0.0000
```

I am guessing the same principle might be used, but then I need to add to every line that has `Z5.0000`

```
G00 X 0.0000 Y 0.0000 Z 10.0000
M05 G00 X 24.5230 Y 44.6619 Z 5.0000
M03 G01 X 24.5230 Y 44.6619 Z 0.0000 F 180.0
G01 X 24.5585 Y 45.2432 Z 0.0000 F 180.0
G01 X 24.6723 Y 45.8451 Z 0.0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\A(?:(?:(?!\bF 180\.0\b).)+\R)+\K^(?=.+?\bF 180\.0\b)`
- Replace with: `M03` *<-- there is a space after M03*
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\A                  # beginning of file
(?:                 # non capture group ()
  (?:               # non capture group (1 line that doesn't contain F 180.0)
    (?!             # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
      \b            # word boundary
      F 180\.0      # literally 
      \b            # word boundary
    )               # end lookahead
    .               # any character but newline
  )+                # end group, may appear 1 or more times
  \R                # any kind of line break
)+                  # end group, may appear 1 or more times
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position(i.e. skip all lines before the first occurrence of F 180.0)
^                   # beginning of line
(?=                 # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
  .+?               # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  \b                # word boundary
  F 180\.0          # literally 
  \b                # word boundary
)                   # end lookahead
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

---

The second replacement is similar but simpler:

- Find what: `^(?=.+?\bZ 5.0000\b)`
- Replace with: `M03`

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Great, this was a whole lot shorter than what I was trying to find
[G]01\s[X]\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s[A-Z]\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s[A-Z]\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s[A-Z]\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\r\n[G]01\s[X]\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s[A-Z]\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s[A-Z]\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s[A-Z]\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\r\n

Comment: @DavidWilliams: You're welcome, glad it helps. If it works for you, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). You can also review your old questions and choose the one that works for you.

Comment: Sorry, this formula found the first instance only and not the remaining. silly me, did not test past what I could see on the screen when running it.
There are thousands of F 180.0 through the file, and this only added to the very first find, not the others.

Comment: @DavidWilliams: Sorry, I don't get you, in the question you asked for replacing the first instance and now you want to replace all occurrences. Please, edit your question and add a complete test case.

Comment: @DavidWilliams: Have a try with a caret `^` instead of `\A` at the beginning of the regex.